# jQuery - problem using .css() with ajax data

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

This should be really simple but for some reason I'm stumped on this...

I'm trying to set the position of an element on page load from ajax data

like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "session_data.php",
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#dragable_box').css( data );
        console.log("Stored Session Data: " + data);
    }
});
```

the `data` variable returns a correct result as I can see it in the console and I tried copying in the result as a test and it positioned the element as expected. It just wont work with `data`...

I tried with and without `async: false`

What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Comment: If you are expecting a json result try to add the `dataType: 'json'` to ajax options.

Comment: @Šime it is an echo response from PHP so I presume just a text string?

Comment: if you pass in a string into the css method, then jQuery tries to read the value of the CSS property which name is the string that you passed in. That's why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yep just figured that out, I have now made sure It is properly formatted json, declared it with `dataType: 'json'` and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things about css():
.css() with one string parameter like `.css('font-size')` will return the font size of the matched element.
`.css('font-size', '1.1em')` will set the font size of the matched element to 1.1em.
`.css({'font-size':'1.1em'})` will also set the font size of the matched element to 1.1em.

Also, if you are meaning data to be an object literal like {'text-color':red} you probably need to add the dataType:'json' parameter to your .ajax() call.  It is most likely a string that looks like an object literal when you print it to the console.  Declaring your return type to be json will cause jQuery to evaluate the result and give you an object literal that you can pass to .css().

Comment: @offex What do you mean by dictionary? An object?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript "dictionaries" are objects. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: @offex I guess you mean object literal. JSON string: `'{ "foo": 1 }'`, object literal: `{ 'foo': 1 }`

Comment: Yes this is what I was trying to do. Thanks for your help. Also worth noting I had to use double quotes, not single quotes for properly formatted json ;-)

Comment: Nice job figuring it out. Although, I would think single quotes or double quotes would work since both are valid in JavaScript.

Comment: @offex I would have thought so too but according to http://www.json.org/ it should be double quotes and it didn't return anything when it was single quotes